# The updated data from model is not getting populated on view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

---

I am developing a jQuery Mobile App using MVC 4 Razor.

On page load I am displaying some default information from database with the help of below code,

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => MyModel.MyEntity.SomeProperty, MyModel.MyEntity.SomeProperty)
```

i.e. populating a Label with some property from my model.

This works fine very first time.

Now, I have one dropdown on my view and the requirement is when user will change the dropdown list option I have to get the data related to that option from database again and display this updated information.

This is the problem area and the updated information is not getting displayed on the view but I can check that updated information is coming from the database.

I am tracking changing drop-down selected option via below statement:-

```
$('#ddlDropdown').change(function())
```

And then calling some Ajax function to execute one method from controller to get the updated information.

Answer (score 0):

If info comes from database do client code and the label is not updating then there must be some error on your updating code, probably related to referencing it.

But it's difficult to point the error without any code. Can you put here the code inside your change function?